# Setting absolute positioned DIV to the same y-coordinate of another DIV using jQuery offset()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, offset

I can't seem to find the answer on the internet, and the jQuery offset() doesn't seem to be working as intended. Here's the situation:

What I am trying to do is vertically align to two divs. One is an inline-block with indeterminate location (y-coordinate depends on how much proceeding content there is.) The other div has complimentary information, and I want it to sit to the side of the other div in a margin like area of the site.

To my understanding of how jQuery.offset() works, that should be able to acquire the coordinates of the content div relative to the document, which can then be used to assign the absolute position of the marginal div. However, when I call offset() on the content div, I get a position of (0px,0px) which is clearly inaccurate.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Here is my code:

```
// Find the div we want to position to (works)
var related_node = $('#content-note-n').attr('data-nid');
var node_obj = $('#node-' + related_node);
// Get the offset position of that div (does not work- returns 0,0)
var position = node_obj.offset();
alert("Top: " + position.top);
$('#content-note-n').css('top', position.top);
```

Here is the relevant HTML (I'm using a CMS, so this is vastly simplified):

```
<section id="zone-content">
  <aside id="region-side">
     <div id="content-note-n" data-nid="n">
       <h3>Note N</h3>
     </div>
  </aside>
  <div id="region-content">
    <div id="node-n">
      <div class="node-content">
         <p>Content for Node N</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Can post CSS if that also helps, but none of the elements are display=none, which jQuery says will break offset().

**Update:**

Have tried copying my exact code into jsFiddle (excluding css), and it works as intended there. Will now try copying over css.

**Update:**

Copied over all of the CSS too into jsFiddle, and it works still. I'm so confused.

Comment: Could you show some html? Also consider using `.data('nid')` to get nid value

Comment: Thanks. I will try to put up the relevant code. I will also give data() a try, but like I said, I'm able to get the right div (verified by the jQuery object having the corresponding classes) but its call to offset returns a 0 position.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a test case ... this works fine for me :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( initialise );

function initialise() {
var myObject = $("#my_div");
var myposition = myObject.offset();
$("#positioned").css({ 'top' : myposition.top , 'left' : myposition.left });

}
</script>
```

with this html

```
<body>
<div id="positioned" style="position:absolute;">overlap</div>
<div>Hello</div>
<div style="margin: 50px"><div id="my_div" type="text" name="name">original</div></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I see how you've reworked the css call differently, but the object the offset call returns is where the problem is arising. My guess is it has something to do with my html or css?

Answer (score 0):

The content node was being printed twice by the CMS. One in the content section, the other in a hidden section (which sat above visible one in the element hierarchy.) jQuery was returning only the node from the hidden section, hence the 0 position. When I added a class to the selector, jQuery began returning two elements, which is how I discovered this issue. My guess is that because I was sending a selector string with only an ID identifier, jQuery was intelligently only sending back a single element.

So to answer the original question, the best practice is to of course alter how the CMS prints the ID for the hidden copy of the node. The quick fix though was to add "#section-content" to the selector to make it "#section-content #node-n".